# BeautifulSoup4: Extracting tables, now how do I exclude certain tags and bits of information I do not want

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to extract coin names, price, and market cap from coinmarketcap.com. I first tried using soup.find_all to search for certain tags with a specific class but it always picked up information I didnt need or want. So instead I used find_all to search for 'td' and then planned on using a for loop to look for specific class names and to append those to a new list and then print that list but it returns a data type for some reason.

```
coin_table = soup.find_all('td')

class_value = 'sc-1eb5slv-0 iJjGCS'
    
for i in coin_table:
    if class_value in coin_table:
        list.append(i)
print(list)
```

But this returns:
`<class 'list'>`
to the console even though im not asking to see the data type. Very new to beautifulsoup and coding in general so sorry if this is a very basic question. Still trying to get my head around all of this stuff.

Comment: Don't scrape it, use the [api](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/listing?start=1&limit=100&sortBy=market_cap&sortType=desc&convert=USD,BTC,ETH&cryptoType=all&tagType=all&audited=false&aux=ath,atl,high24h,low24h,num_market_pairs,cmc_rank,date_added,tags,platform,max_supply,circulating_supply,total_supply,volume_7d,volume_30d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RJAdriaansen mentioned, you don't need to scrape website when they provide `api`. Here is how you do it with `requests` library:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/listing?start=1&limit=100&sortBy=market_cap&sortType=desc&convert=USD,BTC,ETH&cryptoType=all&tagType=all&audited=false&aux=ath,atl,high24h,low24h,num_market_pairs,cmc_rank,date_added,tags,platform,max_supply,circulating_supply,total_supply,volume_7d,volume_30d'
response = requests.get(url)

data = response.json()
```

This will give you json data. Now you can grab all you need by accessing correct keys:

```
final_list = []
temp = []
for each_crypto in data['data']['cryptoCurrencyList']:
    temp.append(each_crypto['name'])

    # each_crypto['quotes'] gives you list of price and market gap of each crypto
    for quote in each_crypto['quotes']:
        # assuming you want to get USD price of each crypto
        if quote['name'] == "USD":
            temp.append(quote['price'])
            temp.append(quote['marketCap'])

    final_list.append(temp)
    temp = []
```

Final result would look like this:

```
[
    ['Bitcoin', 34497.01819639692, 646704595579.0485],
    ['Ethereum', 2195.11816422801, 255815488972.87268],
    ['Tether', 1.0003936138399, 62398426501.02027],
    ['Binance Coin', 294.2550537711805, 45148405357.003],
    ...
]
```